# TypeError: trace(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not method

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I get this weird error when I start my script I really don't know why this error is caused or by what it's caused. It would be very very nice if some of you guy's could help me out with this error:)

Error message:

```
  File "c:/Users/supre/Documents/Python Programs/neuralnet/optimize_graph.py", line 11, in trace
    traced = torch.trace(model.forward)(xample_inputs=(x, hidden)) 
TypeError: trace(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not method
```

This is my code:

```
import argparse
import torch
from model import SpeechRecognition
from collections import OrderedDict

def trace(model):
    model.eval()
    x = torch.rand(1, 81, 300)
    hidden = model._init_hidden(1)
    traced = torch.trace(model.forward)(xample_inputs=(x, hidden))
    return traced

def main(args):
    print("loading model from", args.model_checkpoint)
    checkpoint = torch.load(args.model_checkpoint, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
    h_params = SpeechRecognition.hyper_parameters
    model = SpeechRecognition(**h_params)
    model_state_dict = checkpoint['state_dict']
    new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in model_state_dict.items():
        name = k.replace("model.", "") # remove `model.`
        new_state_dict[name] = v

    model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)

    print("tracing model...")
    traced_model = trace(model)
    #print(type(traced_model))
    print("saving to", args.save_path)
    traced_model.save(args.save_path)
    print("Done!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="testing the wakeword engine")
    parser.add_argument('--model_checkpoint', type=str, default='NameOfYourCheckpoint', required=False,
                        help='Checkpoint of model to optimize')
    parser.add_argument('--save_path', type=str, default='path/where/you/want/to/save/the/optimized/model', required=False,
                        help='path to save optmized model')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Thank's for every help in advance

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation on SpeechRecognition, especially for `forward`?

Comment: @Acccumulation No but I have a link of the repo. Should I give you the repo link?

Comment: @Acccumulation could you please add me on discord because I could tell you then more about the error and what I think it could caused by. Name:CodeForce1#8083

Comment: Getting the documentation is a basic step. I don't see how you can be using a module without knowing what it does. I'm vacillating between posting a comment or an answer. I think that it's likely that if you put `forward()` instead of `forward`, that will solve the problem, but that's ultimately speculation.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try:)

Answer (score 0):

In `traced = torch.trace(model.forward)(xample_inputs=(x, hidden))` you are passing a method i.e `model.forward` you should be using something like this
`traced = torch.trace(model.forward(x))` if your model is already had an instance with parameters